# How to update WKWebView when Dynamic Type size changes?

Tags: ios, dynamic, types, accessibility, wkwebview

I must be missing something simple:

I have an app with a WKWebView with web content that responds to Dynamic Type changes. When the app starts, the Dynamic Type size setting is correctly applied.

The problem is that when Dynamic Type size is changed in Settings and you return to the app, the WKWebView does not re-render with the new settings.

I’ve tried:

- Reloading the content (no change)
- Creating a new WKWebView instance (still shows old Dynamic Type size)

The only thing seems to update how Dynamic Type is reflected in WKWebView seems to be restarting the app.

Anyone know if there’s a way to update WKWebView instances to reflect Dynamic Type size changes without restarting the app?

Comment: This you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. I found this article and I am doing what it explains works, but it is not working for me. However, this is a drop-dead simple example and the CSS we have in our web app is much more complicated. I am going to pour over the article some more to see if there's something I'm missing.

https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-dynamic-type-with-web-views/